# Two routers with one acting as switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, routing

I have 2 routers.

- Router_1 : it's a ZTE ; it is the one getting the internet connection from my ISP by using dsl
- Router_2 : it's a DLink DSL 2750u (not connected to anything right now)

My questioin is :

I want to use Router_2 as a switch. I mean by that, I will connect to Router_1 by WiFi.

From that, all computers on the LAN will have 2 gateways to access the internet : Router_1 as default gateway and Router_2 as alternate gateway.

Can I do that ?
How can I do that ?

*Problem :* The problem is I dont want to use any kind of physical connection to connect the two routers. Below is a scrrenshot of the Router_2 configuration pannel. It explains my problem.

I know you guyz can help me find a way to circomvent this problem.

[Screenshot of Router_2 ethernet / dsl configuration menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kcLo.png)

Comment: Disable DHCP in 2nd router, then it will act as a switch.

Comment: @Moab I cant access it's configuration panel since through 192.168.1.1 since I'm using router one as interface with the ISP

Comment: If both routers support WDS, you're in business. If not, there are ways you can fake it, but they tend to be fragile and unreliable. Instead, I'd recommend using some other device to bridge the two routers, such as powerline adapters (AV1200 or better) or dedicated WiFi bridges.

Comment: Connect router 2 to another pc to access the config page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see if both routers will support wireless bridging.  Usually if they are different brands (and not business equipment) they won't work outside of the other's family unless you put a custom firmware on them.

Comment: What you are saying is that even if they support both wireless bridgind if they are not of the sme brand it wont work ?

Comment: It depends, sometimes they won't. But if both support bridging you can try for sure.